# Jquery Ajax not working in ios safari but data inserted to database

Tags: php, ajax

my ajax not working only in IOS safari or chrome but when in browser PC / laptop is working but data still inserted to database

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('resaller.submit_join', app()->getLocale()) }}",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                email: email,
                first_name: first_name,
                last_name: last_name,
                birth: birth,
                company: company,
                phone: phone,
                addrs: addrs,
                country: country,
                province: province,
                city: city,
                distric: distric,
                post_code: post_code
            },
            success: function(data) {
                var param_val = {
                    id: data,
                };
                var param = $.param(param_val);
                url_s = window.location.origin + '/' + path[1] + '/reseller/join/questionnaire?' + param;
                window.location.replace(url_s);
            }
        })
    }

})
```

also this ajax used when user click the submit form button .

Comment: try to include fail function and log the result to check the reason if fails. Check your url too if it's correct